# Using an array in an array but lose the index

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to use an array in an array to pass to guzzle as parameters.
I've created an guzzleRequest function and want to pass additional parameters to the function.

It adds the array, but gives an "0" => which the other side doesn't process and so it gives me a empty input back.

This is what I do:

```
$parameters =   ['json' => [
                    'roles' => $roles
                        ]
                ];

$res = $client->request($method, $discord->baseUrl.$url, [
    'headers' => [
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization'     => 'Bot key'
        ],
    $parameters
]);
```

But then it gives me this back:

```
array:2 [▼
  "headers" => array:3 [▶]
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "json" => array:1 [▼
      "roles" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "126272446419566593"
        1 => "259316851031539713"
        2 => "259335660589023233"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

The "0 => array:1 [" line should be removed and "json" should be at the same level as "headers"

Like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  "headers" => array:3 [▶]
  "json" => array:1 [▼
    "roles" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "126272446419566593"
      1 => "259316851031539713"
      2 => "259335660589023233"
    ]
  ]
]
```

How will I accomplish this?

Comment: `$parameters =   'json' => [ 'roles' => $roles];`  replace with this code.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)? It contains a lot of information and interesting examples. Then you can take a look at the big list of PHP [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). You don't need any of them here, but use it at a reference for the future.

Comment: @JeesKDenny That gives an unexpected =>, while if I first declare the variable as an array, the result is the same unfortunatly.

Comment: @axiac Yes I did reed the documentation. What part is mostly interesting in this case?

Comment: What about the sections ["Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) (it contains an example that exposes nested arrays, as yours) and ["Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax "](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) (the example shows how to assign a value to a specific key and how to remove the value associated to a key, as it seems you need)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `$parameters` inside the square brackets doesn't merge the arrays, it nests it inside. Put both keys in a single array.

```
$parameters = [
    'headers' => [
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization'     => 'Bot key'
        ],
    'json' => [ 'roles' => $roles ]
];
$res = $client->request($method, $discord->baseUrl.$url, $parameters);
```

Comment: I also found this solution myself. :) I'm doing it a little bit different now with passing $params1 and $params2, but in the end it's the same: http://i.imgur.com/cDlufet.png

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this

```
$parameters = ['json' => [
                    'roles' => $roles
                 ]
              ];

$res = $client->request($method, $discord->baseUrl.$url, [
    'headers' => [
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization'     => 'Bot key'
        ],
    "json" => $parameters["json"]
]);
```

Comment: Hi Azis, I would be able to do that if json was something that has to be sent everytime.
Per example: If I want to get the information of a user, no json information should be sent. Otherwise I would get a 400 BAD REQUEST in return.